# NativeScript: Get string from interop.reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, interop, nativescript, nsdata

To start, here is my code:

```
var buffer = malloc(interop.sizeof(interop.types.UTF8CString));
var fillBuffer = mac.getBytes(buffer);
var bytes = new interop.Reference(interop.types.UTF8CString, buffer);
var hexMac = bytes[0];
```

The variable 'Mac' is an NSData objected retrieved from CoreBluetooth. It is the scan response from a BLE device, which contains the peripheral's MAC address (00:0b:57:a2:fb:a0).

This problem is linked to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46504035/little-endian-byte-order-ios-ble-scan-response) question I had posted earlier.

The solution provided is great; however, I cannot seem to implement this in nativescript :

(instancetype)stringWithFormat:(NSString *)format, ...;

Intellisense tells me the method doesnt exist on type NSString.

Due to that issue, I decided to go another route (as you can tell). I am filling a buffer with the bytes of the MAC address. In the code above, bytes[0] equates to 0xb57a2fba0.

I am now trying to convert that (which is an interop.Reference) into a string that I can store on the back-end (preferably in the xx:xx:xx:xx:xx format).

I have been at this all weekend, and cannot seem to find a solution. I even broke down objc!foundation.d.ts to figure out if stringWithFormat was supported, to no avail.

The nativescript community slack was unable to provide a resolution as well.

Please help if you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about NativeScript at all, but given the other code you wrote, I assume you're calling `+alloc` first, and so mean to use `-initWithFormat:` (an instance method that initializes) rather than `+stringWithFormat:` (a class method which handles allocation and initialization).

Comment: Unfortunately that produces the same result: "Property 'initWithFormat' does not exist on type 'NSString.' 

I tried this after +alloc, and tried +stringWithFormat: without.

What frustrates me is that your answer is golden, with the issue appearing to be a limitation of NativeScript.

I opened an issue here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4910

Thank you so much for your help Rob. I have been trying to get my employer to switch to native code for this project but it does not look like we will be able to until early next month.

Comment: `…withFormat:` is a vararg method, so it's possible those don't import? But if this is JavaScript(?) then you can always just convert there, right? `bytes.toString(16)` and pad it with a leading zero if less than 16? I assume there's a way to convert JavaScript strings back to NSString if you need that? (I'm guessing; again, I don't know anything about NativeScript). Best of luck.

Comment: Your comment led to a possible resolution. It is a bit messy, but it works.:

var hexMac = bytes[0].toString().replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'" <>{}]/g, '').split(":")[1];`